# How to creat real time data sql server with blazor

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor

I try to make web blazor with real time database from sql server .I try with SqlDependency but don't know where to put SqlDependency.start()  .
Can you give me a suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can't use `SQL Server` for **Realtime** database

### Alternative

1. You can use [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) for managed **realtime** and store data in `sql server`
2. You can use [Firebase Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database?gclid=CjwKCAjwpKCDBhBPEiwAFgBzj-SirJyHqvZ01mhXaG1j8Vy6PQlLX-Mj4sb1kSUu_WCCc4UtPdDVxhoCZwYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) not need sore data in sql server but can store if you needed